# Solidity - "DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique"?

Tags: solidity

contracts/simplestorage1.sol:7:20: DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
function store(unit256 _favoriteNumber) public {
^-----^

pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract SimpleStorage1 {

```
uint256 favoriteNumber;

function store(unit256 _favoriteNumber) public {
    favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your code Please see the function argument you have typed unit instead of uint. Correct code is like

```
function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
}
```